Initrd Boot issue after update libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file:
After a recent update of packages, I'm unable to boot
0.794007) Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (Ubuntu Core 2019): c1d57b8f6b743f23ee41f4f7ee292f06eecadfb9'
0.794402] zswap: loaded using pool izo/zbud
0.795407] Key type fscrypt registered 0.795422) Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
0.795461] Key type trusted registered
0.755981) Key type encrypted registered
0.796005) AppArmor: AppArmor shal policy hashing enabled
0.796399] integrity: Loading X.509 certificate: UEFI:MokListRT (MOKvar table)
0.796548] Integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority: ad91990bc22ab1f517048c23b6655a268e345a63'
0.796678] Loading compiled-in module X.509 certificates
0.796928) Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: e3d77283cb57b3f5563b4534d81b6edbb8715d48'
0.796963] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
0.832475) ima: No architecture policies found
0.832519] evm: Initialising EVM extended attributes:
0.832574] evm: security.selinux
0.832605] evm: security.SMACK64
0.832631] evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
0.832662] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
0.834987] evm: security.SMACK64MMAP 0.837253] evm: security.apparmor
0.838913] evm: security.ima
0.840342] evm: security.capability 0.842204] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
0.843392] PM: Magic number: 8:153:584
0.844513] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
0.849051] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2036K
0.850548] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 3356K
0.860594] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 30720k
0.862490] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2036K
0.863998] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1344K
0.870106] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
0.871201] Run /init as init process

Loading, please wait...
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory udevadm: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
udevadm: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Begin: Loading essential drivers done.
Begin: Running/scripts/init-premount done.
Begin: Mounting root file system Begin: Running/scripts/local-top
done.
Begin: Running/scripts/local-premount modprobe: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /bin/btrfs: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have already tried to:

boot with the recovery option
re-generate the initrd
tried older kernels
re-installed libzstd

nothing helped.
What can I do?
